# Launch a background web search

Tags: android

I am trying to launch a websearch using data input from a user.  The data is input through TextEdit boxes. Upon submission of the data, i would like my program to: 1) search for a specific webpage based on the user input 2)Find specific elements at the webpage 3) Display the webpage.

Here is an example:

User Input (in a non browser/webview page) 
          1) Store Name: Macey's 2)Zip Code: 77471

In the background my program will:
    1) Find the Macey's website
    2) Find the store nearest zip code 77471
    3) Load the Web page for the store nearest zip code 77471

Obviously there is a lot of error handeling, exceptions, ect that would go along with this. For the sake of making this example "easy" lets pretend that 1) A the Macey's main page exists 2)A sperate page for the 77471 store exists. 3)There is a link to the 77471 store on the Macey's main page.

I have the code for getting the user input variables and i know how to launch the webview.  What i dont know how to do is to search for the Macy's home page, then find the link i am looking for on the homepage and navigate to it.  Loading the webview is not the problem. Find the data is.

Below is my current code. Right now i am setup so that the user will navigate to the webpage they are looking for but i would rather handle the searching for them, if it is possible.

public void InitializeWebView(){

```
        portal = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_Portal);

    WebSettings Settings = portal.getSettings();
    Settings.setSavePassword(false);
    Settings.setSaveFormData(false);
    Settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    Settings.supportZoom();     

        portal.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
                           }
    });
```

}

public void searchAndShow(String Store, String zip){
         portal.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}

Answer (score 0):

You can get search result in JSON format from google using their API. [Here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje_snippets) is a nice example in JAVA. Just don't use key parameter until you do not have a vlid key.